# WPF WebBrowser control, jQuery, Windows 10 - Long running script error

Tags: jquery, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control, windows-10

I have a wpf application that is using the WebBrowser control to render a website that I have. The website relies on jQuery 2.1.4. The website is using the default html doctype and has the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` tag. I have also added a registry key for the wpf application which sets FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to 9999. All this was working just fine in Windows 7 and 8 running IE 9-11. I've now upgraded to Windows 10 and once in a while I'll get an error that states:

> Stop running this script?
>
> A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.

After stopping the script, I get a bunch of script errors that basically state that jQuery or '$' is undefined. I assume the long running script was jQuery. If I close the WebBrowser control window and reopen it everything works fine again, but then later if I open up the WebBrowser control I'll get the same error messages.

Is this an issue with me having the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key set to 9999? Will setting it to, say, 11000 or 11001 fix this issue? It's difficult to test since I don't always get this error. Most of the time if I open up the WebBrowser control it will work just fine. Does anyone know anything about this issue or have the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score -1):

The FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key seems to break the Webbrowser control in Windows 10. For me, I had to remove the key from the registry. This wasn't really a problem for me, since i have control of the code, and by using the  in the HTML i got the same result as with the key in Win 7/8/10.

Comment: by using the what?

Comment: what is solution for this problem